# How to link the output of teradata sql query to an excel sheet?

Tags: sql, excel, teradata

I am new to teradata. I run a sql code on teradata which gives me a table as the output. I want this table to be populated in an excel sheet directly whenever I run this code. how can I do it?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is yo run the query from Excel via ODBC. Therefore you setup an external data source in Excel. Whenever you refresh the data, the query us executed against Teradata.

In Excel 2010 it's at `Data`, `From Other Sources`, `From Microsoft Query` or from `Data Connection Wizard` if you have an OLEDB setup.

Answer (score 1):

Teradata SQL Assistant has the ability to automatically export results to a csv which Excel is usually the default program to open csv.

You'll want to select "Export Results" from under the "File" menu in SQL Assistant.

If it's not exporting properly then select Tools->Options->Export/Import and change the delimiter to a comma.

Unfortunately from within SQL Assistant there's no way to automatically save as xls or xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ODBC connection from excel itself is the fastest way for one time use.

If you are planning on running something many times you could run from another language, it adds a step but is highly worth it if you care to schedule tasks that run regularly.
Here is some code in python:

```
import pyodbc as pc

conn = pc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password;QUIETMODE=YES;')
curs = conn.cursor()

rows = curs.execute("""
    select *
    from table
    ;""").fetchall()

f = open('myfile1.csv', 'w')
for row in rows:
    s = [str(x) for x in row]
    f.write(','.join(s) + '\n')
    print ','.join(s) + '\n'
f.close()
```

The default program used to open .csv files is excel.

If you need it to be an excel file explicitly you can use the xlwt module or have python execute vba code to import into an existing file:

```
import win32com.client
import xl

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
f = xl.Workbook("C:\...\Target.xlsm")
excel.Run("%s!testmacro"%f)
```

Instant reporting!